# Why "for in" inside "for loop" can't change each input value in form element with each object value

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom, ecmascript-6

**Hello Everyone!**

I want to make some `function()` that is useful for changing each `input` values in selected form ​​dynamically with each `Object` values, but sadly my example code below it only show `"pineapple"`

```js
document.getElementById("change-val").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let dataObj = {
    fruit1: "melon",
    fruit2: "mango",
    fruit3: "pineapple"
  };
  let FormInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (let index = 0; index < FormInput.length; index++) {
      for (let keyObj in dataObj) {
          FormInput[index].value = dataObj[keyObj];       
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="change-val">Change Value</button>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="apple"/>
  <input type="text" value="watermelon"/>
  <input type="text" value="banana"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The nested loop is always looping till the last property which is `[fruit3] === pineapple `

Comment: What's the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use nested loops. Use one loop that gets the corresponding property with the index.

You can use `Object.values()` to get an array of the property values.

```js
document.getElementById("change-val").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let dataObj = {
    fruit1: "melon",
    fruit2: "mango",
    fruit3: "pineapple"
  };
  let FormInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  let fruits = Object.values(dataObj);

  for (let index = 0; index < FormInput.length; index++) {
    FormInput[index].value = fruits[index];
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="change-val">Change Value</button>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="apple" />
  <input type="text" value="watermelon" />
  <input type="text" value="banana" />
</form>
```

Comment: so, what if the object key like `{green_fruit: "melon", dark_green_fruit: "mango", yellow_fruit: "pineapple"}`, should I do `for loop` again for get every object key? It's the same, isn't it?

Comment: How are those supposed to correspond to the inputs? Objects don't necessarily retain their property order.

Comment: I've updated it to use `Object.values()` so the names of the keys are not relevant.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I didn't think of using `Object.values()`